# Para que serve o comando git push -u?

Tags: git, bitbucket

eu sei que o comando push envia o arquivo para o repositório virtual, mas não sei o que o PUSH -U faz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define o ramo remoto padrão para o ramo local atual.

Qualquer `git pull` comando futuro (com o local branch checked-out) 
tentará trazer os commits da `<remote-branch>` ramificação local atual.

Uma maneira de evitar ter que explicitamente fazer `--set-upstream` é 
usar o sinalizador abreviado `-u`, juntamente com o `git push` da seguinte maneira

```
git push -u origin local-branch
```

Isso define a associação upstream para quaisquer tentativas de push / pull futuras automaticamente.

Referência está [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031946/what-does-set-upstream-do) !